# Javascript - Disable multitouch

Tags: javascript, multi-touch

I'm trying to block multitouch on my 1920x1080 touchscreen.

```
this.el.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {

  if (this.multiTouch.disable(e)) {

    this.triggerTouch(e);

  }

}.bind(this));
```

The `multiTouch.disable` function returns true or false. This is the function:

```
disable: function (e) {

  if (e.touches.length > 1 || e.targetTouches.length > 1) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    return false;

  } else {

    return true;

  }

}
```

So in this function I check how many touches are registered. If there is more than one touch registered it's multitouch so it should be blocked.

But when I add the following statement to the `this.el` eventlistener `console.log(this.multiTouch.disable(e))` I get logs like this:

```
true TouchPoint.js:36
(11) false TouchPoint.js:36
true TouchPoint.js:36
10false TouchPoint.js:36
true TouchPoint.js:36
(7) false TouchPoint.js:36
true TouchPoint.js:36
(6) false TouchPoint.js:36
true TouchPoint.js:36
(8) false TouchPoint.js:36
true TouchPoint.js:36
(7) false TouchPoint.js:36
true TouchPoint.js:36
(6) false TouchPoint.js:36
```

This is when touching the screen with three or more fingers. The first touchstart always registers only one touch, so the disable function will always return true the first time.

How can I correctly block multitouch with JavaScript?

Comment: Could you just debounce the touch listener? My feeling is that the more you work against these kinds of device features the harder your time will be, the web is embracing this stuff so easy methods of sidestepping aren't made available. I would suggest figuring out how to work with rather than against it.

Comment: This project is being build for a custom kiosk setup, containing a 1920x1080 pixels touchscreen controlled by a Brightsign (https://www.brightsign.biz/) unit. 

This setup is really slow and struggles with multitouch input. That's why in this case I just want to disable multitouch. Debouncing isn't an option.